# How to share a folder with windows server 2019 that requires a login to access

Tags: home-networking, file-sharing, windows-server-2019

I am trying to setup a home network with windows server 2019 as a file server. I made user accounts on the server and setup a shared folder giving access to those user. But when I go to login I get the following error.

"*You do not have permission to access \PC_NAME contact your network administrator to request access*"

How can I get it to prompt me with a login option?

I am not using a domain or active directory because that sounds scary and really complicated seeing as all I want to do it share folders.

[image]

Comment: Problem with permission inheritance?

Comment: You need to access \PC_Name\folder and then it should work. That is how you would map the folder.

Comment: If you are in a workgroup and not a domain, ensure you have the user account set up on BOTH the client workstation and the server machine with the same username and the same password. When prompted, then put in that credential and see what happens. I assume you are not in a domain environment here and just a workgroup where both the server and the workstation are connected to the same workgroup (e.g. home). The syntax is `\\servername\sharename` or `\\serverip\sharename` by the way.

Comment: I had considered it might work if I used the same logins as the ones on the local machines. But that means if the user changes there account on the computer I would need to change there access on the server. Also if I setup another computer I would than need to make a new account on the server. Can't I just have a shared folder with a login required?

I am able to see the shares but I am not able to login it just says I do not have access. I would have access if they let me login it :)

Comment: I don't deal with workgroups that often and only commented based on my experience with a small shop and software they use requiring a share and how I got it to work. You might try to see if granting `everyone` to the share and to the folder both will do the job. Otherwise, you could create a generic login with the same username and password across the machine(s) and server and just have them type that in the first time they launch the share shortcut, etc. after a reboot. This will make it separate from other usernames and passwords. You could login script it out too so users don't do anything.